# How to set autofit authomatically in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this question, I don't know if its possible or not but I want the column to automatically become bigger or shorter if I enter a longer text or I delete it. I don't want to double click every time, its a big file.

Thank you

Comment: Define what you mean by automatically?  Are you scripting this?  Would setting multiple rows manually be acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is by using VBA.
This requires you to save the file as .xlsm and enable macro.

Right Click the the sheet tab at the bottom and select "View Code"
and paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Where "C:C" is replaced by the column you want to autofit.
This also works for a range of cells like "A:E".
Good luck!